# Slow count query with group

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization, group

I have a common aggregation **query**:

```
SELECT 
      products.type, 
      count(products.id) 
   FROM 
      products
         INNER JOIN product_colors 
            ON products.id = product_colors.product_id 
           AND product_colors.is_active = 1 
           AND product_colors.is_archive = 0 
   WHERE 
         (products.is_active = 1 
      AND product_colors.is_individual = 0 
      AND product_colors.is_visible = 1) 
   GROUP BY 
      type
```

[image]

It lasts in the order of 0.1 seconds. The indexes look fine, tmp_table_size = 128M and
max_heap_table_size = 128M. Why they are so slow? Classic selects are fast, but as there is group and count, no.

**Indexes on products table:**

[image]

**Indexes on product_colors table:**

[image]

**Explain SQL:**

[image]

**EDIT Product indexes:**

[image]

Comment: try running this same query by prefixing "explain" (explain <your sql>) and then the server will tell you which indexes it is using (or if its not using).

Comment: you have mentioned 2 tuning parameters of server, hope you have taken a look at innodb buffer pool size. I have experienced improvements by setting this parameter to about 50% of physical ram

Comment: I increased innodb_buffer_pool_size from 16M on 64M. It is little bit better, but query still durate 0.3s (i would expect minimal 10x times less, like another queries). I added explain SQL image, can you check it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the query is using index on "is_active" field of products table because you have this condition in where clause. You also do a "group by type" so it may help to have a composite index on products table, for is_active and type.
As regards server tuning, you may have to tune couple of other parameters depending on the engine type you are using. Just google for this, but in my experience innodb buffer pool size has big impact. If you have say 16GB ram on the server, try to increase the buffer pool to at least 4GB from your current setting and then restart mysql server.

Comment: Well, yeah, but if I do the composite index is_active and type, it won't be used when the query is just is_active or not?
Increasing from 16M to 4G (I have 32G RAM) made only a very small difference.

Comment: If the first field in composite index is "is_active" then this index will be used by query with "where is_active=1". In general the first field in any composite index works for queries searching the combination of fields or the first field only.

Comment: Read 150K and process rows in 0.1 sec -- Not bad.

Comment: `ON products.id = product_colors.product_id` says that there are many glasses for each color?  Not the other way around?

Comment: @Sudhir - once the buffer_pool is "big enough", almost nothing else is worth tuning.

Comment: @Sudhir - Composite indexes -- Only the _leftmost_ columns are useful, not "any combination".

Comment: @RickJames, yes you are right when you say leftmost column, thats what I said as first field.

Comment: @Sudhir so it is better make just composit indexes with most important column on the beginning than more one column's indexes?

Comment: @RickJame it is 0.1-0.5s and such queries is more, so together it is couple seconds. Point is, that "count" durates 0.1-0.5s and query withou "count" durates 0.001 - 0.01s on the same records. And yes each glasses has couple colored variants.

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to analyze your queries and then decide. Here is what I follow:    - add indexes for fields used in where clause, join, group by, order by  - if the where clause has an "and" condition then create composite index else individual indexes.

Comment: in your case, you have a where clause and group by on main table, so suggested composite index

Comment: Ok, do you mean, that is the best one composite index with many boolean columns (10-20) in product table?

Comment: There is a max of 16 columns in one index.  You might limit the list to the most common or most selective.  Keep in mind that if you don't test a particular flag in the `WHERE`, that column and the following columns in the index won't be used.

Comment: For example -- Notice (in the EXPLAIN) how it stopped with "product_id" since you did not test "is_active".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing is not optimal for what you are asking.  Instead of just having an index on each column individually (can be a big waste), you should have composite indexes that better match what you are trying to query and be covering enough to handle any group by or orderings.

In this case, you primary query is ACTIVE products and ordering by type.  So I would have a SINGLE index on your primary table on `(is_active, type, id)`.  This way, your WHERE criteria is up front via Is_Active, then your order by via Type and finally the ID that qualifies the record.  In this case, your query can get all it needs from the INDEX and not have to go to the raw data pages.

Now, your secondary table.  Similarly should be composite index.  First based on the criteria of the join between tables, THEN based on its restrictions you are looking for, thus:  `( product_id, is_active, is_archive )`.  Why you have two columns of Is_Active and another for Is_Archive, dont know.  I would think that if something were in the archives, it would not be active to begin with, but just a guess on that.

Anyhow, with the optimized indexes should help.

One last consideration on your count(product.id).  Do you intend DISTINCT Products, or all records found.  So if a one product has 8 colors, do you want the ID counted as 1 or 8.

```
count(*) would give 8
count( distinct product.id ) would give 1
```

Comment: In some products i need without and else width "distinct". It is good point. Is better have one composite index with all parametres with table products (most of them is bolean)? I added screenshot my product indexes to origin post, but i do not know if index will aplly in  all cases. Query whit dirated 0.5 is now 100x faster.

Comment: @tomasr, so solution question resolved at 100 times faster I guess?  And also, you can do BOTH counts in a single query...  count(*) AllEntries, count( distinct products.id ) UniqueProductCount

Answer (score 0):

Give these a try:

```
products:  INDEX(is_active, type)
product_colors:  INDEX(product_id, is_individual, is_visible,   is_active, is_archive)
```

Since `products.id` cannot be NULL, you may as well say `COUNT(*)` instead of `count(products.id)`.  (Or, as DRapp points out, maybe you *need* `COUNT(DISTINCT products.id)`